# how to add customize arrow in select sub menu in twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Please can any one help me, I want to add and customize select arrow in select dropdown like this arrow image.

[image: arrow]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [**silviomoreto's fork of bootstrap dropdown**](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) then,

the **bootstrap menu arrow** can be added with the <kbd>**show-menu-arrow**</kbd> class.

**HTML:**

```
 <select class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BjtNY/270/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

See css triangles:

> http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

And after just play with positions of the arrow.

For example:

> http://jsfiddle.net/CpHTh/

```
content: "";
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 5px solid black;
position:relative;
top: -23px;
left: 10px;
```

Comment: For me, at **Google Chrome on Windows 8** it works perfect. What are you using ?